# Why do we want these properties to be in the extended factorial function?

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, gamma-function

$$\Gamma(x)= \int_0^ \infty e^{-t}t^{x-1}dt \ \ \ \  \ \ \ x>0.  $$

Bohr and Mollerup showed that the gamma  function is the only positive  function $f$ defined on $(0,\infty)$ that has these properties

1. $f(x+1)=xf(x)$
2. $f(1)=1$
3. $f(x)$ is a continuous
4. $f(x)$  is log convex

My question is why are these properties matter (I mean 3, 4 the first two are essential )? I get that it is probably useful defining $\Gamma$ to be continuous but why it should be log convex it seem to be a random and
absurd thing that has no motivation but I am sure that there is a reason why it matters and why did Euler choosed this property when he gave this integral .

Comment: Minor note: the Bohr-Mollerup theorem dates from the 1920s and AFAIK the role of log convexity in characterizing $\Gamma$ was not appreciated before then. Certainly when Euler and D. Bernoulli and others were first considering continuous extensions of the factorial function (~ 1730s), they made no mention of log convexity, and in particular did not expressly "choose" $\Gamma$ over alternatives on this basis. (One can think of Bohr-Mollerup as "retroactive motivation" for why $\Gamma$ stands out from other options, but there is no evidence that Euler or contemporaries thought this way.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first condition implies that $f$ has the form $f(x)=f(\{x\})\prod_{n=0}^{\lfloor x\rfloor-1}(n+\{x\})$ (where $\{x\}$ is the [fractional part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) of $x$), and thus, since also $\Gamma(x)=\Gamma(\{x\})\prod_{n=0}^{\lfloor x\rfloor-1}(n+\{x\})$,

$$f(x)=\frac{f(\{x\})}{\Gamma(\{x\})}\Gamma(x).$$

The first factor is periodic; if it isn’t constant, its logarithm must alternate between being convex and concave. Since $(\log\Gamma(x))''\to0$ for $x\to\infty$, that means that $\log f(x)$ eventually alternates between being convex and concave on every interval $[n,n+1]$. That’s not a nice property for an interpolation of $n!$ to have.